# Dynamically updated querysets?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class M(models.Model):
    ...
    seen = models.BooleanField()
    ...

    def set_seen(self):
        self.seen = True
        self.save()
```

Then I have this code in a views.py function:

```
m_not_seen = M.objects.filter(seen=False)
m_seen = M.objects.filter(seen=True)

for m in m_not_seen:
    m.set_seen()
```

After the last line is executed, it seems like m_seen is updated automatically to include all the entries that were in "not seen" previously. I don't want the queryset to be updated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django querysets are lazy, as the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) says:

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

In your case, writing `m_seen = M.objects.filter(seen=True)` does not go to the database until you start looping through it or whatever it is you end up doing with it. At that point, the not seen ones have already been updated to seen.

The documentation goes on to talk about [pickling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets) and other ways you can force a QuerySet to be evaluated. In your case, you probably just want to call `list()` on the QuerySet, just be aware that this will load all the results into memory.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if list() is the least expensive way to force evaluation? Maybe len() is cheaper?

Comment: It is the same cost, because your call was filter. If you just want to count, you should use filter().count()